# Generate 4000 unique pseudo-random cartesian coordinates FASTER?

Tags: python

The range for x and y is from 0 to 99.

I am currently doing it like this:

```
excludeFromTrainingSet = []
while len(excludeFromTrainingSet) < 4000:
    tempX = random.randint(0, 99)
    tempY = random.randint(0, 99)
    if [tempX, tempY] not in excludeFromTrainingSet:
        excludeFromTrainingSet.append([tempX, tempY])
```

But it takes ages and I really need to speed this up.

Any ideas?

Comment: I might be missing something but aren't there only 10000 unique integer *x-y* coordinates for *x* and *y* between 0 and 99?

Comment: How is it random if you're excluding what you've already put in there. And why are you using a list instead of a tuple?

Comment: @fideli Lol. That is a good point. Anyways, I might need to do this for larger ranges so the question is still relevant.

Comment: Vincent Savard has a [better answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170054/generate-4000-unique-pseudo-random-cartesian-coordinates-faster/4170127#4170127) that is about twice as fast as mine. You should accept that one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vincent Savard has an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170054/generate-4000-unique-pseudo-random-cartesian-coordinates-faster/4170127#4170127) that's almost twice as fast as the first solution offered here.

---

Here's my take on it. It requires tuples instead of lists for hashability:

```
def method2(size):
    ret = set()
    while len(ret) < size:
        ret.add((random.randint(0, 99), random.randint(0, 99)))
    return ret
```

Just make sure that the limit is sane as other answerers have pointed out. For sane input, this is better algorithmically O(n) as opposed to O(n^2) because of the set instead of list. Also, python is much more efficient about loading locals than globals so always put this stuff in a function.

EDIT: Actually, I'm not sure that they're O(n) and O(n^2) respectively because of the probabilistic component but the estimations are correct if n is taken as the number of unique elements that they see. They'll both be slower as they approach the total number of available spaces. If you want an amount of points which approaches the total number available, then you might be better off using:

```
import random
import itertools

def method2(size, min_, max_):
    range_ = range(min_, max_)
    points = itertools.product(range_, range_)
    return random.sample(list(points), size)
```

This will be a memory hog but is sure to be faster as the density of points increases because it avoids looking at the same point more than once. Another option worth profiling (probably better than last one) would be

```
def method3(size, min_, max_):
    range_ = range(min_, max_)
    points = list(itertools.product(range_, range_))

    N = (max_ - min_)**2
    L =  N - size
    i = 1
    while i <= L:
        del points[random.randint(0, N - i)]
        i += 1
    return points
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure someone is going to come in here with a usage of numpy, but how about using a set and tuple?
E.g.:

```
excludeFromTrainingSet = set()
while len(excludeFromTrainingSet) < 40000:
    temp = (random.randint(0, 99), random.randint(0, 99))
    if temp not in excludeFromTrainingSet:
        excludeFromTrainingSet.add(temp)
```

EDIT: Isn't this an infinite loop since there are only 100^2 = 10000 POSSIBLE results, and you're waiting until you get 40000?

Comment: sets don't have an `append` method.

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion :

```
def method2(size):
    randints = range(0, 100)
    excludeFromTrainingSet = set()

    while len(excludeFromTrainingSet) < size:
        excludeFromTrainingSet.add((random.choice(randints), random.choice(randints)))
    return excludeFromTrainingSet
```

Instead of generation 2 random numbers every time, you first generate the list of numbers from 0 to 99, then you choose 2 and appends to the list. As others pointed out, there are only 10 000 possibilities so you can't loop until you get 40 000, but you get the point.

Comment: This is actually slower. the code for `random.choice` is just `return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]` so not only is it still making a call to the random number generator each time, but it's also taking the length of the list.

Comment: From my tests, it's actually faster than yours. Why? (Genuine question, I'm no Python expert.) For my tests, I obviously replaced the for loop with a while loop identical to yours, and put the code in a function.

Comment: because your algorithm is wrong, now that I look at it. You're only testing 10,0000 random pairs and there's no guarantee that they'll all be unique. So you could very well be returning less than the desired amount. Mine tests as many pairs as is necessary to get the desired amount.

Comment: As I said, I didn't use this code exactly for my tests. I'll edit and let you look at it again (please!).

Comment: Missed your edits. Looks like you're right. 'python' uses a more convoluted generator for `randint` now that I look into it. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4):

Make a list of all possible (x,y) values:

```
allpairs = list((x,y) for x in xrange(99) for y in xrange(99))

# or with Py2.6 or later:
from itertools import product
allpairs = list(product(xrange(99),xrange(99)))

# or even taking DRY to the extreme
allpairs = list(product(*[xrange(99)]*2))
```

Shuffle the list:

```
from random import shuffle
shuffle(allpairs)
```

Read off the first 'n' values:

```
n = 4000
trainingset = allpairs[:n]
```

This runs pretty snappily on my laptop.

Comment: Much better than the accepted solution because there are only 10000 to choose from. This is similar to what I was going to type. I'll add my solution with random.sample instead (which is only a little bit faster).

Comment: @Justin Peel. Again, how do you say that this is better when your solution runs 'slightly' faster than this one and mine runs significantly faster than that.

Comment: @aaronasterling, sorry, I should have looked at all of your solutions. Most people put their best answer first so I stopped there. I removed my answer appropriately. I apologize for being hasty and not thorough

Answer (score 1):

You could make a lookup table of random values... make a random index into that lookup table, and then step through it with a static increment counter...

Answer (score 1):

Generating **40 thousand** numbers inevitably will take a while. But you are performing an O(n) linear search on the excludeFromTrainingSet, which takes quite a while especially later in the process. Use a set instead. You could also consider generating a number of coordinate sets e.g. over night and pickle them, so you don't have to generate new data for each test run (dunno what you're doing, so this might or might not help). Using tuples, as someone noted, is not only the semantically correct choice, it might also help with performance (tuple creation is faster than list creation). Edit: Silly me, using tuples is *required* when using sets, since set members must be hashable and lists are unhashable.

But in your case, your loop isn't terminating because 0..99 is 100 numbers and two-tuples of them have only 100^2 = 10000 unique combinations. Fix that, then apply the above.

Answer (score 0):

Taking Vince Savard's code:

```
>>> from random import choice
>>> def method2(size):
...     randints = range(0, 100)
...     excludeFromTrainingSet = set()
...     while True:
...         x = size - len(excludeFromTrainingSet)
...         if not x:
...             break
...         else:
...             excludeFromTrainingSet.add((choice(randints), choice(randints)) for _ in range(x))
...     return excludeFromTrainingSet
... 
>>> s = method2(4000)
>>> len(s)
4000
```

This is not a great algorithm because it has to deal with collisions, but the tuple-generation makes it tolerable. This runs in about a second on my laptop.

Comment: In python 2 you can get a slight speed boost with `while 1` instead of `True`. `True` is treated as a global in Python 2 and as a constant in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
## for py 3.0+
## generate 4000 points in 2D
##
import random 
maxn = 10000
goodguys = 0
excluded = [0 for excl in range(0, maxn)]
for ntimes in range(0, maxn):
  alea = random.randint(0, maxn - 1)
  excluded[alea] += 1
  if(excluded[alea] > 1): continue 
  goodguys += 1
  if goodguys > 4000: break
  two_num = divmod(alea, 100)  ## Unfold the 2 numbers
  print(two_num)
```